# How to pd.read_xml from zipfile with UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml, zip

I have a Zip archive with a number of xml files, which I would like to read into a Pandas data frame. The xml files are UTF-16 encoded, hence they can be read as:

```
import pandas as pd

# works
with open("data1.xml", encoding='utf-16') as f:
    data = pd.read_xml(f)

# works
data = pd.read_xml("data1.xml", encoding='utf-16')
```

However, I cannot read the same file directly from the Zip archive without extracting it manually first.

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

# does not work
with zipfile.open("data1.xml") as f:
    data = pd.read_xml(f, encoding='utf-16')
```

The problem seems to be the encoding, but I cannot manage to specify the UTF-16 correctly.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZipFile.open` reads in binary mode.  To read as UTF-16 text wrap in a `TextIoWrapper`.

Below assumes a `test.zip` file with UTF-16-encoded `test.xml` inside:

```py
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
import io

z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
with z.open("test.xml") as f:
    t = io.TextIOWrapper(f, encoding='utf-16')
    data = pd.read_xml(t)
```

If the .zip file has a single .xml file in it, this works as well and is documented in [`pandas.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) (see the **compression** parameter):

```py
data = pd.read_xml('test.zip', encoding='utf-16')
```